# Debian minimal installation

Tags: system-installation, lxde, debian-installer

I have downloaded an iso of Debian by https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst,
then:

```
apt-get install lxde-core
```

and later:

```
apt-get install xorg sudo chromium pulseaudio
```

I have restarted pc, but I cannot change to the "graphic mode".
What do I need to do to change to "graphic mode"

Comment: So how have you tried to start up the graphical environment?

Comment: If I remember well you shuold `startx`

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the Comments above, you will need to input:

```
$ startx
```

With the things you have installed, you will need to do this each time you start the machine.

The alternative is to install a Display Manager - XDM, WDM, LightDM, Slim etc.

I would go for LightDM which is non-desktop-environment specific. So install:

```
$ lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the default .target for systemd to boot into.

You can do this with:

`systemctl set-default graphical.target`

This will enable a graphical login (with a display manager) rather than a console login.

See systemctl(1) & systemd.special(7) for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, during installation I needed a file, required me by netinst, essential for the good success of the installation or of the interface graphical boot (as in my case).
As explained at the end of "http://guide.debianizzati.org/index.php/Debian_e_firmware", it is obligatory to download one of the three proposed files on a pendrive, even if installation may continue...
I do not know if I can add it later.
Perhaps I'll install it again, in the following order:

apt-get install xorg xinit

apt-get install slim

apt-get install lxde-core

Comment: Arch Wiki: Warning: The SliM project has been abandoned (the project homepage is down, leaving a github mirror), and is not fully compatible with systemd, including logind sessions. Consider using a different Display manager or Xinitrc.