# is there a way to auto run x-windows?

Tags: linux, debian, x11

OK,... So First and foremost, I am a Green Cherry or a VERRY, VERRY NEW NEWBIE where Linux is concerned. So if this has been asked, please post a link to the answer and kindly do not downvote me :).

I have:

- Kernel 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11)
- Debian 10.2 (Buster)
- Current version of X-Windows (I have no idea how to get the version number)

I've checked Google, this network, as well as other sites and searched with no such (except the concept of installing something else).

So my question is this.

**How do I get xWindows to autoload for all users without writing a script**

**update 1**
This is where it gets ”stuck” [image: I’m stuck]

**Information Update**

- **Which image did you use?** Network payload
- **Did you notice the questions on desktop environments, what did you answer?** Unfortunately, No, I did not notice anything to do with the desktop environment.
- **Also, on the (very) rare occasion the hardware is not compatible or requires extra work, is it an old machine? What's your video card?** The laptop is from 2002

Comment: The X Windowing System normally autostarts on Debian.  Did you install any desktop environment during the installation, I think Gnome is selected by default?

Comment: yes, please give us details on your installation process. Which image did you use? Did you install from the installation media (USB/disk) or through the network? Did you notice the questions on desktop environments, what did you answer? Also, on the (very) rare occasion the hardware is not compatible or requires extra work, is it an old machine? What's your video card?

Comment: Well https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342268/5132 is close.

Comment: You are correct about Gnome. But for some reason after install TTY1 gets stuck and I have to switch over to TTY2hat could literally be the problem. However, I didn't see an option to set that up. But I could have simply missed it :P   .

Comment: Gets "stuck" during installation?  The first X session usually runs on tty7.

Comment: Not stuck during installation. During boot. Every time it boots, it sticks at a specific spot and then I typically go to. TTY2 and then log in, and I'm golden.

Comment: Where does it get stuck?

Comment: I added a pic to show where it gets ”stuck”

Comment: @msb updates are to follow 

Comment: OK, let me see if I understand: 1. you downloaded the netinst image from debian. 2. you installed it without any problems. 3. ever since installation, when you start the laptop, the boot process gets stuck at that point in the screenshot. 4. at that point, you go to TTY2 and are able to log in fine, and use the system normally, no issues. 5. from there, you're able to manually start X and use the graphical interface, no issues either. 6. What you're asking is how to have X load automatically. Which could also be the same as asking how to complete the boot process. Is this correct?

Comment: @msb... this is correct.

Comment: Ok. Since you're able to load X, it's not a hardware issue, which is good. :D The selection of Desktop environment can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB-gmnvYDao&t=560 You can select more than one, maybe that would help. Also, I had installation problems in the past and reinstalling using a different mirror fixed for me. Since you have a fresh installation, you could try that too. In my experience and opinion, it's easier to just reinstall than to fix the problem, when it's a fresh installation and you won't lose anything. :(

Comment: @msb - The mirror I have been using is debian.cc.lehigh.edu. I've been using them in the past because their pipe is a large one. And Yes, I did mention I was a very GREEN newbie. I literally am. I get started on a project and then it gets forgotten because of other commitments. UGH!!!